# is it possible to compile C files to an .app instead of a .exe file?

Tags: c, macos, exe, compilation

if there is no way to turn your C files to a .app macintosh executable, then how do you even create any mac apps?

**UPDATE: It was because I didn't have GCC installed.**

Comment: What tool are you using that's generating (Windows?) .exe files on a Mac platform?

Comment: Relevant: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/shell-script-mac-apps

Comment: What is your source of information that says that "there is no way to turn your C files to a .app macintosh executable"?

Comment: @oli im doing programing on a windows platform. im just interested to try something new.

Comment: @Joe: Ah.  Well if you want to develop Mac applications, you may find it easier to do the development on the Mac, because the toolchains there will generate Mac binaries by default.

Answer (score 5):

Well if you wanted to know about `Object Files` you may refer:

[Creating object files from source files](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_13.html).

[The GNU Compiler Collection on Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/tools/gcc_overview.html)

Otherwise i do not understand what you want to ask.

Comment: thanks for your help you guys! its just i dont know where to download compile for a mac OSX 10.4.11 with Intel core Duo.

Comment: Mac OS X install gcc compiler - http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/726/mac-os-x-install-gcc-compiler/

Comment: Mac OS X comes with Xcode. It may be an older version (mine was 3.2.x), but it allows you to compile C, Objective-C and C++ and it produces .apps as well as console applications.

Comment: You were using NSLog, that's why I thought so. Xcode is pretty cheap ($5) or free.

Answer (score 3):

There is of course a way to compile C files into Mac executables. But to do that you need a proper set of tools: A compiler and runtime libraries for Mac. If you are on Linux or Windows this will be a *cross compile* where you use one system to compile something for another system.

The GNU Compiler Collection on Mac OS X link that @Acme provided is probably a good start.